# How to move back to flutter stable

Tags: flutter

I am trying to develop a desktop application and I tried to switch to dev mode using this command flutter channel dev but since then all the flutter command I tried to run are not working. Below sis the error it's showing everytime I run any flutter command.
flutter/version: Operation not permitted

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Could you please update the question with `flutter doctor -v` response

Comment: it doesn't working either same error

Answer (score 2):

in terminal write `flutter channel stable`

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to remove the current Flutter installation folder and extract a fresh one with the desired version. You do not have to change anything else, just extract the Flutter SDK in place of the old one and run `flutter doctor`.

Answer (score 1):

just run

```
flutter channel stable && flutter upgrade
```